# Howto set working directory for embedded python interpreter

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program that is embedding Python.

The python scripts being run may write some temporary files and I would like to set the "working directory" to a path of my choosing, in order to control where these files are written to.

The python scripts themselves are located in the users local appdata folder.

I know how todo this in python: import os; os.chdir('newfolder')

However, I would want to do it using Pythons C functions. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: You probably know how to call Python functions, otherwise you couldn't make use of the integrated interpreter, so what keeps you from making those calls? Anyhow, a working directory is a process property, it applies to both C++ and Python code. However, I'd rather use an explicitly set variable instead of relying on volatile things like a working directory.

Comment: I do know how to call python functions. It is in my question. I just wonder if there are any Python C functions to use for it. Like the Py_SetProgramName() function for example.

Comment: Calling functions is part of any tutorial for embedding Python, so I'm wondering what you are doing. Can it be that you simply call Python from the C++ process? That's not what people normally mean with embedding Python.

Comment: The Py_* set of functions are to be used from a C or C++ program when python is embedded. That is what I'm doing. My question is if there is a Py_?? function that sets the working directory for the Python process. That's all.. there is not anything complicated going on at all :)

Comment: Ah, okay, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any [OS-specific API](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change%20working%20directory%20C%2B%2B) to change the working directory. Since the working directory is a process property, it applies to both C++ and Python code.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Since I don't want to change the working directory for the whole process, I decided to go with an explicitly set variable instead. Thanks!